# Copy structure between objects

Tags: vertices

I've been trying this for months, but to no avail. I really need your help.

I have two objects, both are human faces, object 1 has more faces and vertices than object 2

I would like to know how to make object 2 with the same 3D and UV appearance as object 1, while maintaining its original vertices.

I know it may sound crazy, but there is a person in my work area who does this. And I really need to know how to do it, but unfortunately he is not willing to teach.

Comment: Did you try the shrinkwrap modifier ?

Comment: something around "transfer mesh data" operator or "data transfer" modifier.

Comment: Gorgeous, I have not tried, I will search on.

Comment: Lemon, I tried, but I was unsuccessful. It just doesn't change anything. And I follow tutorial videos but nothing happens